# What's convention for naming a class or method as "class" in Python?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pep8

Let's say I have a class in Python like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, classs):
        self.classs = classs
```

Now, what's convention for naming a parameter (and class property) `classs`? I saw `classs` as well as `klass` and I'm wondering: is there some convention for it? Didn't find it in PEP8.

Comment: i've seen klass, clazz, cls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PEP 8 advises to use a trailing underscore in that case: `class_`.

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles for details:

> single_trailing_underscore_ : used by convention to avoid conflicts
>   with Python keyword, e.g.
>
> `Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I overlooked that example.

Comment: And Django doesn't allow trailing underscores for field names. `(fields.E001) Field names must not end with an underscore.`. Damn :D

Answer (score 2):

The answer of `class_` from PEP 8 is awkward, in my opinion, and possibly problematic as commented elsewhere for that answer to this question. The PyCharm IDE seems to prefer `cls` for class methods, which annoys me for its coder-happy abbreviation, while the arguably more or less readable and understandable `klass` is still a misspelling. So I'd like to throw out an alternative for these situations, including class wrappers and the like:

I use `Class`, which is not reserved due to the casing.

I know a lot of people are going to say that variables names should be lowercase, but the lines between object and type, class and function, variable and pre-defined are all blurred in Python. For instance, if I were to write:

```
NoneType = type(None)
```

would you argue that it should be renamed `NONE_TYPE` because it's global? `NoneType` is a class, though it is not defined using the `class` keyword. Likewise `Class` is a class, although it's also a variable. By capitalizing it, I'm just emphasizing one aspect over another. And I do this for all variables representing types.

Comment: The PyCharm IDE prefers `cls` for class methods because that's what PEP 8 says to do: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments

Comment: Also, I would argue that you shouldn't store the type of None; maybe you've found a legitimate reason to do so, but that seems like a code smell. If on the other hand you are storing the type of a variable, and it happens to be that the variable is equal to `None`, and you want to compare it to the type of None, you could use `if variable_type == type(None): ...`, but in that case the pythonic thing to do would be to use `if variable is not None: ...` Using `Class` works, but it collides with the [convention for class names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names)

Comment: It was a hypothetical example. I don't need NoneType, but neither am I going to construe a more complicated example to illustrate such a simple point. Even the convention for class names makes exceptions for when the class is used differently. It's not too big of a leap to say that this is an exceptional case as well.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a convention. I've seen - and probably used - `klass`, `_class`, and `cls`.